# Vector Pushback Not Working Inside of a Constructor Class

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

## Problem

(Apologies if I use the wrong terminology, I am used to Java constructors, and have just recently tried implementing them in C++)

I have a constructor class called `FileHandler` that will make a new instance of a `FileHandler` with two vectors inside of it (The constructor has been dulled down, as there is a lot of extraneous code not pertinent to this issue):

```
class FileHandler { 

public:
    std::vector<std::string> fullPath, fileNames;

    FileHandler() {
        //Creates two vectors
        fullPath;
        fileNames;
    }
```

As far as I am aware, this should create two vectors inside of the instance of `FileHandler`, which can be manipulated normally. However, from a separate file, I call the `.push_back()` method (again, dulled down):

```
//  This vector is pre-made and pre-filled before this is called, 
//  and I have verified it _is_ filled
std::vector<FileHandler> fileHandlers;

FileHandler testInstance = fileHandlers.at(index);
testInstance.fullPath.push_back("a_string_here");
std::cout << testInstance.fullPath.at(0);
```

And I get the following error (at runtime):

```
std::out_of_range at memory location 0x00000...
```

---

## What I've tried so far

I had a suspicion that it might not like trying to `push_back` from outside of the constructor, so I made a separate function inside of the constructor:

```
void addFullPath(std::string fullPath) {
        this->fullPath.push_back(fullPath);
}
```

However, passing a string in a similar way as before:

```
std::vector<FileHandler> fileHandlers;

FileHandler testInstance = fileHandlers.at(index);
testInstance.addFullPath("a_string_here");
std::cout << testInstance.fullPath.at(0);
```

Still gives me the same `out_of_range at memory location` error.

This implies (at least to me) that the second line; being the `.push_back()` method, is not functioning as it should. My main hypothesis at this point is that I am not instantiating the vectors in the constructor in the correct format, or that the vectors cannot be edited, however I am as of yet unsure. Please advise.

Comment: A debugger could tell you for sure. No need to guess. It would also be worth looking into both default member initialization and the constructor initialization section.

Comment: @sweenish I'll give both of those a look, thanks!

Comment: What is the goal of `fullPath; fileNames;` in the constructor body? That won't do anything. it certainly will not create the vectors (they are already created when you enter the constructor body).

Comment: `FileHandler testInstance();` is a compile error because of how `testInstance` is used afterward.. Remove the `()` at the end so it isn't parsed as a function declaration. The constructor does nothing, you can remove that too. Otherwise it works for me: https://ideone.com/VdleXJ

Comment: @RetiredNinja My true code works with a vector of FileHandlers, so the constructor there is a placeholder. I will edit the post now to reflect this, as it is pretty pertinent.

Comment: It would help if you put together a [mcve] showing the actual code you are having trouble with.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I managed to solve my issue, but I will keep that in mind for the future. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After running the following similar dummy code, everything worked normally.
There may be an error elsewhere in the extraneous code you did not show.

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_MYCLASS_H
#define UNTITLED_MYCLASS_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class MyClass {
public:
    std::vector<std::string> a,b;
    MyClass();
};
#endif //UNTITLED_MYCLASS_H
```

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass() {} //the vectors are dynamic and don't require initialization here
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

int main()
{
    // should not be file() which is a function call for the default constructor
    MyClass file; //declares default object instance
    file.a.push_back("a string");
    std::cout << file.a.at(0);
    return 0;
}
```

```
untitled\cmake-build-debug\untitled.exe
a string
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I have just edited my post with more information that may affect this, mostly pertaining to the fact that my `testInstance` is selected from a vector of `FileHandler`s

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved:

My problem was the following line of code:

```
FileHandler testInstance = fileHandlers.at(i);
```

I falsely assumed that the `testInstance` would inherit all properties of `fileHandlers.at(i)`, making it completely usable, however this was not the case. Replacing:

```
FileHandler testInstance = fileHandlers.at(index);
testInstance.fullPath.push_back("a_string_here");
std::cout << testInstance.fullPath.at(0);
```

With:

```
fileHandlers.at(index).fullPath.push_back("a_string_here");
std::cout << fileHandlers.at(index).fullPath.at(0);
```

Yields expected results.

Comment: Both of those should produce the same result for the snippets given. The first makes a copy of the `Filehandler` and then modifies the copy. The second modifies the `Filehandler` in the `fileHandlers` vector directly. That distinction is important, but for the code shown it does not matter. Once again I assume this isn't the actual code you're having trouble with or you haven't shown something important about the `Filehandler` class. I feel you've fixed the problem by accident and have just kicked the can down the road a little bit, but good luck anyway.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It took me a bit to figure out what was happening here, and honestly, it was a big brainfart on my part. Making the instance wasn't the problem, but after the code was run *on the instance*, I was never setting the `vector.at(i) = instance`, meaning the code I was performing was not being 'saved' per-say. Anyways, thanks again for the help